# Let's say a.java is in folder x, and b.java is in the parent folder, how would i code b.java to be able to access a.java in b.javas code?

Tags: java, eclipse, directory

I can't find any info on how to call a different java file from a different folder anywhere.

Heres a diagram of what I wanna do[image]

So for example

If the java file was in the same folder you would do:

```java
HUD.HEALTH
```

but what would you do if the java file was in a different folder.

Comment: Hello, was my answer helpful?

Comment: yes it was, sorry i forgot to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you normally work in **one** folder, the so-called source folder. In this folder the classes can be divided into packages, usually using a certain pattern, for example com.company.something. In this case, a class is applied via import. The keyword import and the package name in which the class is located are specified. If they are external resources, the classes are included as external resources (.jar files), nowadays build tools like gradle and maven are used for this. Once the dependencies are imported, they can be used as well.

[image]

If you have two local projects, and want to access a class from project B in project A, for example, you work with the IDE. In Eclipse I would simply go to ProjectB's Build Path settings and add ProjectA. I recommend Intellij as IDE, there you solve it as follows:

Steps in IDEA ( You won't need these below steps if you follow below mentioned best practices):

1. Right click on project and select open module settings
2. Go to dependencies tab
3. click plus sign and add the module you want to use.

Best practices:

Never use project class in another project, always create a nice interface and use that interface in other projects.
If possible use Dependency Injection to manage different projects and their dependencies (this internally uses interfaces to do this).
Use build tools like Gradle and Maven to manage build process.